# Turn Every 2 rows of Dataframe into 1 row x 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe (df) that looks like this:

```
    date        ID  Team    P   F   T   TO
0   20160101    537 Bobcats 5   10  0   3
1   20160101    538 Spartans8   10  1   4
2   20160101    539 Tigers  7   8   2   3
3   20160101    540 Vikings 10  5   0   1
4   20160101    541 Smurfs  5   3   0   2
5   20160101    542 Winners 6   9   1   0
```

I am trying to condense every 2 rows into 1 and still keep all of the fields so that the new dataframe (new_df) looks like this:

```
    date        ID1 Team1   P1  F1  T1  TO1 ID2 Team2   P2  F2  T2  TO2
0   20160101    537 Bobcats 5   10  0   3   538 Spartans8   10  1   4
2   20160101    539 Tigers  7   8   2   3   540 Vikings 10  5   0   1
4   20160101    541 Smurfs  5   3   0   2   542 Winners 6   9   1   0
```

What is the most efficient way to do this using Python?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is just to figure out the opponent for each team and then merge the table to itself. I'm assuming based on your example that ID 2n-1 played against ID 2n. If that's not true, adjust this accordingly (e.g. you can compute the opponent based on the index).

```
D['ID_opp']=D['ID'].apply(lambda x:x-1 if x%2==0 else np.nan)
D


    date    ID  Team    P   F   T   TO  ID_opp
0   20160101    537 Bobcats 5   10  0   3   NaN
1   20160101    538 Spartans    8   10  1   4   537
2   20160101    539 Tigers  7   8   2   3   NaN
3   20160101    540 Vikings 10  5   0   1   539
4   20160101    541 Smurfs  5   3   0   2   NaN
5   20160101    542 Winners 6   9   1   0   541
```

and then do the merge

```
D.merge(D,left_on='ID',right_on='ID_opp',suffixes=('1','2')).drop(['ID_opp1','ID_opp2','date2'],axis=1)

       date1    ID1 Team1   P1  F1  T1  TO1 ID2 Team2    P2 F2  T2  TO2
0   20160101    537 Bobcats 5   10  0   3   538 Spartans 8  10  1   4
1   20160101    539 Tigers  7   8   2   3   540 Vikings  10 5   0   1
2   20160101    541 Smurfs  5   3   0   2   542 Winners  6  9   1   0
```

Comment: If "next row down" is really the way to figure out the opponent, then something like this would work: `D['ID_opp']=[D['ID'].iloc[i-1] if i%2==1 else np.nan for i in range(D.shape[0])]`